# Why does std::thread::spawn() panic on error instead of returning a Result?

Tags: rust

In the Rust's standard library, there are two ways of spawning a thread:

- [`std::thread::spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html)
- [`std::thread::Builder::spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html#method.spawn)

The difference between them is that when the OS fails to create the thread, the former panics while the latter returns a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html).

Why doesn't `std::thread::spawn()` simply return a `Result` instead of panicking? From my point of view, this would be safer. Also, it would unify the return type of both functions. What is the motivation behind "panicking by default" in this particular case?

Comment: Questions about "motivation behind an API" are generally not a good fit for SO because, while there may be many conjectures there is often little objective information that can be supplied with such. The most basic answer is: "because that's how the API was written"; and this answer applies to many API methods across many languages.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/d8f8f7a58c7c8b3352c1c577347865f5a823fee3/

Comment: This is just a short cut, I don't see the problem. By the way, https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/thread/mod.rs.html#412-416. Look this is a trivial function.

Comment: @Stargateur I don't think OP is confused about the implementation details. They want to know why does *this* function need a shortcut that panics? Why doesn't a function like `File::open` have such a shortcut? I agree with @user2864740 though; very rarely can you discover the "why" behind such decisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: as mentioned, the exact reasoning can be hard to fathom; we can however look at the facts.*

> From my point of view, this would be safer.

It would not.

Panicking does not introduce memory or thread unsafety and is not an error-signalling method that can be ignored.

It's perfectly safe.

> Also, it would unify the return type of both functions.

It would. Which would be a mixed blessing.

To cite Emerson:

> A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds

Remember that in Rust a `Result` cannot be ignored, it *has* to be acknowledged and dealt with. This somewhat diminishes the value of a short-cut. Compare:

```
let h = Builder::new().spawn(f).unwrap();

let h = spawn(f).unwrap();

let h = spawn(f);
```

The latter is much more of a short-cut!

> What is the motivation behind "panicking by default" in this particular case?

**Convenience**.

The thread API is built around two complementary APIs:

- the `Builder` API offers fine-grained control over every single aspect, at the cost of verbosity,
- the free function API offers a terse way of quickly spawning a thread, at the cost of control.

This way, whether you want control or terseness, there's a standard API for you.

The *cost* of not doing so is that many people would introduce an `unwrap` by default function. Each their own. And it would be harder to hop projects.

Answer (score 2):

Rust panics on "out of resources" like OOM. In this case the "can't create thread" error must mean out of hard or soft limited resource (see [pthread_create errors](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)). Technically there are other errors, but looking at the exposed API I'd say you can't reach them from safe Rust code and I assume the windows errors are pretty similar. But Rust wouldn't be a systems programming language if there weren't an escape hatch allowing you to cleanly try some action and check whether it succeeded. For heap allocations this currently means you need to use [unstable APIs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/heap/fn.allocate.html), but these are being improved (as of 11. July 2017 already in the nightly) and most likely stabilized in the future.